# Update UserControl that has been added in Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a ContainerPanel to which I added a UserControl.

Is there a way to access the already added UserControl in order to call an Update Function that has been already declared inside the UserControl?

or

Is it better just to clear the Usercontrol and Re-load it with the updated info?

Cheers,

Comment: Is there not a member variable by the same name as your user control in the code behind?

Comment: Is the user control added dynamically, or is it declared in the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search the panels children for the type you're trying to find (I'm using Linq in the example below).

```
var myControl = myPanel.Controls.OfType<MyUserControl>().FirstOrDefault();
myControl.DoWhatever();
```

Comment: Hey, cheers for the reply, it seems to be working fine. thanks!

Comment: np. just remember that FirstOrDefault() could return null if the control is not found.